# Cannot set property 'webkitTransition' of undefined?

Tags: ionic4

Hello everyone I am working on ionic 4 and face problem while implementing parallax in 'webKitTransition'. I find no solution of this problem. So please tell me. Thank You for your time. Error is given below

ParallaxHideHeaderPage.html:7 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'webkitTransition' of undefined
    at EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.setStyle (platform-browser.js:1118)
    at BaseAnimationRenderer.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/animations.js.BaseAnimationRenderer.setStyle (animations.js:242)

ParallaxHideHeaderPage.html:7 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'webkitTransition' of undefined
at EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.setStyle (platform-browser.js:1118)
at BaseAnimationRenderer.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/animations.js.BaseAnimationRenderer.setStyle (animations.js:242)

```js
import { Directive, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, Renderer, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
selector: '[appHideHeader]',
host: {
'(ionScroll)': 'onContentScroll($event)'
}
})
export class HideHeaderDirective {
@Input('header') header: HTMLElement;
headerHeight;
scrollContent;

constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) { 
console.log(this.header);
}

ngOnInit() {
this.headerHeight = this.header.clientHeight;
this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.header, 'webkitTransition', 'top 700ms');
this.scrollContent = this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName("scroll-content")[0];
this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.scrollContent, 'webkitTransition', 'margin-top 700ms');

}

onContentScroll(event) {
if (event.detail.scrollTop >= 56) {
this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.header, 'top', '-56px');
this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.scrollContent, "margin-top", "0px")

}
else{
this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.header, 'top', '0px');
this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.scrollContent, "margin-top", "56px")

}
}
}
```

```html
<ion-header #head>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>parallaxHideHeader</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding appHideHeader [header]="head">
 <div class="main-content">
    <h2>Parallax Header</h2>
</div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined - Ionic 3, Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47004340/error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-style-of-undefined-ionic-3-angular-4)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your accessing the right element along the element tree. Instead of

```
this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.header, 'webkitTransition', 'top 700ms');
```

use

```
this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.header['el'], 'webkitTransition', 'top 700ms');
```

Same for "this.scrollContent".

Comment: Tanks lot of Work for Me